# Improving the load time of directives in ng-repeat of angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Im working with 1000 rows of data (employees) that are displayed to a user using angularjs and angular-datatables. Things work fine as long as I don't load the *details directive which loads a details page with additional data on the employee* and displays it as a modal.

The data is retrieved in 94ms.
When no directive is included, page load takes about 2s.
With the directive, page load can take more than 20s.

I understand that with the directive being loaded and populated for each row, it slows the page load time, but there has got to be a way to build this so it is more efficient.

The js does make two calls. The first call is to retrieve the employees for the initial load. The second is to retrieve the employee details for the directive.

Should I do a single query and have the service return all the data? Is there a way I can lazy load the data so that the GetEmployeeDetails is only called during the on-click event?

Here's the relevant code:

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in directory.employees">
    <td>{{ employee.LastName }}</td>
    <td>{{ employee.FirstName }}</td>
    <td>{{ employee.Title }}</td>
    <td>{{ employee.DeptAbbr + " | " + employee.OfficeAbbr }}</td>
    <td>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="left">
                <a href="mailto:{{employee.Email}}" title="{{employee.Email}}" ></a>
            </div>
            <div id="right" ng-controller='DetailsController'>
                <img class="to-pointer" src="/includes/images/icons/card-address.png" ng-click="toggleModal()" title="View Contact" />
                <details visible="showModal" modalClass = "modal-sm" templateUrl="details.html"></details>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**controller.js**

```
directoryApp
.controller('DirectoryCtrl', function($resource, 
                $scope, 
                DTOptionsBuilder, 
                DTColumnDefBuilder) {

        var vm = this;
        vm.employees = [];
        vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
            .newOptions()
            .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
            .withDisplayLength(10);
        vm.dtColumnDefs = 
        [
            DTColumnDefBuilder
                .newColumnDef(4)
                .notSortable()
        ];

    $resource('site.com/api/employee/Get')
            .query()
            .$promise
            .then(function(employees) {
                vm.employees = employees;
            });
})
.controller('DetailsController', function($resource, 
                $scope, 
                DTOptionsBuilder,
                DTColumnDefBuilder) {

        var vm = this;
        vm.employee;
        vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
            .newOptions()
            .withPaginationType('full_numbers').withDisplayLength(10);
        vm.dtColumnDefs =
        [
            DTColumnDefBuilder
                .newColumnDef(4)
                .notSortable()
        ];

        $resource('site.com/api/employee/GetEmployeeDetails/')
            .query()
            .$promise
            .then(function(employee) {
                vm.employee = employee;
            });     
});
```

Comment: Use advanced rendering approach shown in docs and let datatables plugin do the rendering instead of using ng-repeat

Comment: move ng-controller outside ng-repeat, that's can make ng-repeat very slow.

Comment: and what does `details` directive do? it can slow it if need to run 1000 times.

Comment: @YOU Of course it's going to slow down the load time. The controller is only being called for each employee. Thanks for the catch. I moved it as suggested and reduced load time down to about 5 seconds.

Comment: @charlietfl I'm looking into the advanced rendering as well as RenderJS.

Comment: @YOU clarified the details directive purpose in 1st paragraph.

Comment: you can try one more thing by using track by syntax in `ng-repeat="employee in directory.employees track by $index"`, but I doubt that 1000 may still take 2 s and 5 s with details directive. may be you should checkout angular-vs-repeat to limit how many its shown on screen.